# How to do Nested ScrollView orientation programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am using two scrollviews as Horizontal UIScrollView -> Vertical UIScrollView -> UIImageView.
On rotation they are working fine but shows black background of Vertical scrollView first and then shows imageView's image.

I want imageView first instead of black background.
Please help.

Comment: Could you please clarify the "hey are working fine" point? Do you see the black background only during the transition while you rotate the device, but once the views are in place, everything looks exactly right?

Comment: yup. But for the first page of vertical scrollView it rotates in normal way as on other apps but for all the other pages it shows full black background and then show the views.